# How to add certain values together in a dictionary in python

Tags: python

```
def statistics():
    monthly_d = {}
    with open("BLS_private.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            monthly_d[row[0]] = {"January":row[1],"Febuary":row[2],"March":row[3],"April":row[4],"May":row[5],"June":row[6],"July":row[7],"August":row[8],"September":row[9],"October":row[10],"November":row[11],"December":row[12]}

    print(monthly_d)
    return monthly_d

statistics()
```

This results in the following dictionary:

```
'2011': {'January': '108207', 'Febuary': '108464', 'March': '108725', 'April': '108989', 'May': '109097', 'June': '109199', 'July': '109374', 'August': '109426', 'September': '109642', 'October': '109781', 'November': '109959', 'December': '110193'}
```

What I would like to do is combine all of the statistics into the dictionary together so I can have an output like this:

```
'2011' : {'234099894'}
```

i.e. just the sum of all of the months inside of the dictionary.

Comment: I haven't combined them as of yet. I'm wondering how to combine them. For every year I need all of the statistics for the year in it. So I'm wondering how to combine it. In the dictionary to get an output of just the year, with the value of all of the statistics afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Just use sum on the `dict.values`. A dict comprehension would be just fine for this:

```
year_sums = {y: str(sum(map(int, m.values())))
                for y, m in statistics().items()}
```

FYI `statistics` can be simplified to a dict comprehension as well:

```
months = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
          'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

def statistics():
    with open("BLS_private.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        return {row[0]: dict(zip(months, row[1:12])) for row in reader}
```

Comment: I edited to fix that @helloimstupidpythonstudent. I forgot to include `.items()` after statistics

Comment: sorry to bother you again; but now im getting an invalid literal for base 10 error. " for y, m in statistics().items()}
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Then somewhere there is malformed data most likely. Ensure all the values can be converted to integer form without error. Remember an empty string will also cause this issue.

Comment: I figured it out! its because in 2008 there was a empty string for some reason, so I changed the csv file. Thank you so much for your help. Your help helps computer science sophomores like me all around the world

Answer (score 0):

```
def statistics():
    monthly_d = {}
    with open("BLS_private.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            total = sum(int(v) for v in row[1:])
            monthly_d[row[0]] = '{}'.format(total)

    print(monthly_d)
    return monthly_d

statistics()
```

That simply sums up all the elements in each row. It will then look like this:

```
'2011' : '234099894'
```

Comment: "total = sum(int(v) for v in row)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' I'm getting a value error. Is it because dictionaries default to being a string?